Extrapolating self-referencing keys from a hierarchy column
I'm working with a dataset in MySQL that includes a hierarchy column with formats like:
1
1.A
1.A.1
1.A.1.a
1.A.1.b
1.A.2
1.A.2.a
1.B.1
1.B.1.a
2
2.A
...

I'd like to build a table with a self-referencing key to the parent (the last value before the most recent dot) by parsing this out on the fly in a SELECT. Is there a way to do this in MySQL or will I need to use an external script?

You should be able to use SUBSTRING_INDEX() or REGEXP_SUBSTR() to extract the part of the string before the last .

Provide your sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired output for this data.

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t1.id, MAX(t2.path) parent_path
  FROM test t1
  JOIN test t2 ON t1.path LIKE CONCAT(t2.path, '.%')
  GROUP BY t1.id
)
UPDATE test t1
JOIN cte ON t1.id = cte.id
JOIN test t2 ON cte.parent_path = t2.path
SET t1.parent_id = t2.id,
    t1.node_name = TRIM(LEADING '.' FROM SUBSTRING(t1.path FROM 1 + LENGTH(cte.parent_path)));
SELECT * FROM test;




id
path
parent_id
node_name




1
1
null
null


2
1.A
1
A


3
1.A.1
2
1


4
1.A.1.a
3
a


5
1.A.1.b
3
b


6
1.A.2
2
2


7
1.A.2.a
6
a


8
1.B.1
1
B.1


9
1.B.1.a
8
a


10
2
null
null


11
2.A
10
A



fiddle
PS. The node name in the source table must be defined as UNIQUE (and maybe NOT NULL).
